# AppleScript (or swift) add hours to time

Tags: swift, date, applescript

I'm trying to add 8Hours to a date (from the clipboard)

```
set date1 to the clipboard
set newdate to date1 + (8 * hours)
display dialog "Purchases were downloaded at " & newdate buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

But this is not working as expected, I'm having the error 
`Can’t make "06/22/2015 08:15:27    " into type number.`

Comment: How is this question related to Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pick the hours as an individual variable, like shown below:

```
set currentDate to current date

set newHour to ((hours of currentDate) + 8)
```

You can also use this for days, minutes and seconds.

This will work. You can then use the variables to construct a new date to be used in the `display dialog`.

PS. Don't forget to change the day if the `newHour` variable is bigger than 24 hours.

**EDIT**

Setting a date to the clipboard can be done like this:

```
set currentDate to current date
set the clipboard to currentDate as Unicode text
```

Getting the current clipboard and adding it to a variable goes like this:

```
set currentDate to get the clipboard
display dialog currentDate
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi NGAFD, that's helpful, however I'm not trying to add 8 hours to the current date but 8 hours from the date saved in the clipboard (a past event) I'm not sure how to set the clipboard as a date so I can add this 8 hours

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, you can call `dateByAddingTimeInterval` on an `NSDate` object.
The time interval is measured in seconds.

```
yourDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(8 * 60 * 60)
```

If you wanted to add another method to add 8 hours directly, you could define an extension:

```
extension NSDate {
    func addEightHours() -> NSDate {
        return self.dateByAddingTimeInterval(8 * 60 * 60)
    }
}
```